# Site Collection url and read-only url, two urls for the same Site Collection

Tags: site-collection, url, read-only

I have a Site Collection with specific users permissions (read, contribute...etc.) on "http://mysitecollection".

I want to have another URL to this (same) Site Collection "http://mysitecollectionreadonly" where all users have just read-only permissions. Is there a way to achieve this?

thanks.

Comment: Is my below answer helps you?

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend your Web application using below mentioned URL.

[Extend claims-based web applications in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/gg276325.aspx)

By extending the web application, it will point the same web application with having another URL.

So now you can set permission to readonly for every user (as per your need).

Comment: yes this is the perfect way to achieve

Answer (score 0):

You can either extend the web application or use host-named site collection
http://dinushaonline.blogspot.com/2014/04/extend-sharepoint-host-named-site.html